# Remove the system sound output when recording with microphone in Python

Tags: python, audio, audio-recording, microphone, pyaudio

Actually I am recording every sound with the microphone, and I would like to filter the input in order to remove the system sound output, to understand clearly the user's voice when music is playing for example (like what Skype does).

I am looking for a Python module which allows to do that in Ubuntu 16.04, or at least something which record the system output.

Here's my script (I am using Pyaudio) :

```
THRESHOLD = 1500
CHUNK_SIZE = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
RATE = 44100
MAX_RECORDING_TIME = 7 # seconds
MAX_SILENCE_UNITS = 65

def is_silent(snd_data):
    "Returns 'True' if below the 'silent' threshold"
    return max(snd_data) < THRESHOLD

def normalize(snd_data):
    "Average the volume out"
    MAXIMUM = 16384
    times = float(MAXIMUM)/max(abs(i) for i in snd_data)
    r = array('h')
    for i in snd_data:
        r.append(int(i*times))
    return r

def record():
    """
    Record a word or words from the microphone and 
    return the data as an array of signed shorts.
    Normalizes the audio.

    the recording stops after 7 seconds or a sequence of 65 silent recording units
    """
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=1, rate=RATE,
        input=True, output=False,
        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK_SIZE)

    num_silent = 0
    snd_started = False

    r = array('h')

    begin_time = 0
    while 1:
        # little endian, signed short
        snd_data = array('h', stream.read(CHUNK_SIZE))
        if byteorder == 'big':
            snd_data.byteswap()

        if (snd_started):
            r.extend(snd_data)

        silent = is_silent(snd_data)

        if silent and snd_started: # we compute the number of silent units
            num_silent += 1
        elif not silent and not snd_started:
            print("start recording !")
            snd_started = True
            begin_time = time.time() # we save the current time
        if not silent:
            num_silent = 0

        now = int(time.time())
        if snd_started and (now-begin_time>MAX_RECORDING_TIME or num_silent > MAX_SILENCE_UNITS):
            break

    print("recording finished !")

    sample_width = p.get_sample_size(FORMAT)
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

    r = normalize(r)
    return sample_width, r

def record_to_file(path):
    "Records from the microphone and outputs the resulting data to 'path'"
    sample_width, data = record()
    data = pack('<' + ('h'*len(data)), *data)

    wf = wave.open(path, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(1)
    wf.setsampwidth(sample_width)
    wf.setframerate(RATE)
    wf.writeframes(data)
    wf.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing sound output completely from a voice recording (usually without the best conditions i.e. a desktop mic in noisy environment), is very hard to do well and there are many filtering techniques although the most simple one comes to mind.

### Removing the system output direct sound

To get the audio system output, you will need to have some sort of [loopback device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12541/can-i-setup-a-loopback-audio-device), probably using [PulseAudio](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/record_system_sound). This way you can open 2 input audio streams, and will be able to receive your microphone data and system output data at the same time (this will work on a blocking approach like you have currently but I would be wary if you swap to callbacks).

The simplest way then, is to subtract all of the values in the system audio output audio block from the block of audio received by the microphone. Assuming there is no real latency issue, then this will remove all of the direct sound coming out of the device from the microphone recording.

Pseudocode:

```
output = microphone_audioBlock - systemOutput_audioBlock
```

You will need to think about a couple of things:

- You will need to check if headphones are used so you aren't still subtracting the sound
- This will not cancel all of the indirect sound (i.e. the reverb / reflections generated in the room)

This method is simple but as I mentioned it will not cancel the indirect sound. There are many methods for cancelling indirect sound but are all generally research concepts.

### Reducing background noise

Other than that you will probably want to reduce background noise ; In DSP terms this is called [noise suppression](http://www.sensear.com/blog/noise-suppression-vs-noise-cancellation-what-is-the-difference).

Since you will only have access to one microphone and won't have great control over the positioning (most likely) there is no straight forward way to implement this without some sort of DSP algorithm implementation. I have attached a couple of places where you can read up on active noise suppression techniques below:

- [Speech enhancement based on a priori signal to noise estimation](https://cairn.enssat.fr/bindocs/publications/SCALART_97-1.pdf)
- [LMS Adaptive Filters for Noise Cancellation: A Review](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b26c/eda431a8b71e78298982ced440232266eb7b.pdf)